# How to engine map in the developed source code in Flutter? (Android)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-engine

I have recently developed an Android App with Google's Flutter Framework. When taking a deeper look into what is going on when the app compiles I saw that flutter builds four blobs of data (non-ELF binary). How does the Flutter engine load that code (my developed source code if I am not mistaken) at runtime?

I searched the Flutter engine documentation for more information, but the only thing I could find is, that the engine "maps in" those blobs (called snapshots); 
Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-engine-operation-in-AOT-Mode)
How does that "mapping in" actually work? I understand, that the flutter engine can communicate with the underlying android runner app via JNI, but how does it load my developed Dart Code?
I tried to read the flutter engine source code, but it's written in C++ and I'm rather unfamiliar with that.

So if anyone has a deeper insight into the startup process of a flutter app for android any new information or suggestions would be appreciated, I can't seem to be able to wrap my head around what's going on with those binary data files.